# Use VBA to Update Conditional Formatting Ranges?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to update the conditional formatting range for about 30 rows of data on a worksheet. Every month I update the data and I want to run a macro to adjust the ranges to incorporate the new month. I've already done this for my charts by updating the end of the series ranges by looping through the ChartObjects and SeriesCollection.

To do this on conditional formatting, everything I've found requires hardcoding a range (either a cell reference or a named range), e.g.:

```
With Worksheets(1).Range("e1:e10").FormatConditions(1)
```

I'd prefer to just loop through the collection of conditional formatting for the worksheet, but I can't find any evidence of this collection existing in the Excel VBA Object Model. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Found an answer here
https://superuser.com/questions/1347262/how-can-i-modify-the-applies-to-property-of-a-cells-conditional-formatting-ru

Answer (score 1):

This is a little convoluted since there isn't really any great way to loop through `formatconditions` in a sheet. But, you can loop through specialcells and then loop through their `formatconditions` and dig in from there:

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim lng As Long

    For Each rngCell In ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllFormatConditions).Cells
        For lng = 1 To rngCell.FormatConditions.Count
            On Error Resume Next
            Debug.Print rngCell.FormatConditions(lng).Formula1, rngCell.FormatConditions(lng).AppliesTo.Address
        Next lng
    Next rngCell
End Sub
```

I poached the `specialcells()` idea from [Dick Kusleika's excellent post on this very subject](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2010/04/16/listing-format-conditions/) at dailydoseofexcel.com blog.

Comment: I read Dick Kusleika's post, which is pretty good stuff. This is a tough one. Unfortunately, the conditional formatting I'm working on is a color scale, which he discusses doesn't work with the code above, as it is a separate object (ColorScale vs. FormatConditions). If I get around to it, I may try to convert your code to work with ColorScale.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code as below: Here Based on condition Highlighted the row in yellow color. You can use your formatting

```
LastColumnARows = WB_Source.Sheets(SheetName.Name).range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  

                    With WB_Source.Sheets(SheetName.Name)

                        For i = 2 To LastColumnARows
                            If .range("A" & i).Value > [Condition] Then
                                With .range("A" & i & ":E" & i)
                                    .Interior.Color = vbYellow
                                    .Font.Color = vbBlack
                                End With
                            End If
                        Next i
                    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

To loop over the existing Format Conditions in a spreadsheet, you can use a loop like this:

```vb
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet")

    Dim AllFormatConditions As FormatConditions
    Set AllFormatConditions = ws.Cells.FormatConditions

    Dim fc As Object    
    For Each fc In AllFormatConditions
        Debug.Print fc.AppliesTo.Address
    Next
```

Now, if you want to modify the AppliesTo range instead of just printing the address like above, you'll need to use [ModifyAppliesToRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.FormatCondition.ModifyAppliesToRange) and pass a range as your argument.

eg.

```vb
fc.ModifyAppliesToRange ws.Range("A42:Z42")
```