Excel VBA macro is unintentionally changing my conditional formatting
I have a couple of macros for my spreadsheet and it seems the main one I run keeps changing the "Applies to" rule of my conditional formatting.
The macro is extremely simple, it just uses the "Remove duplicates" function to remove any duplicate numbers from one column.
My formatting:

It just formats the row of cells based on the checkbox values. Every time I use the remove duplicates macro the "Applies to" value changes to a bunch of specific, sectioned off cells, rather than the big range like I have it set to in the picture.

Is there a way to stop the remove duplicates macro from interfering with my conditional formatting? It's pretty annoying to have to go into the conditional formatting and change every value back to it's original

What is keeping you from using full column references?

or you could just reset them after the remove duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37301441/use-vba-to-update-conditional-formatting-ranges

What is your macro supposed to be doing?  From what I can see, it seems like it might be copy/pasting cells from elsewhere, which means it overwrites the conditional formatting in your sheet with the conditional formatting (or lack thereof) from the source.  You might be better off either using the PasteSpecial method, or setting the Cell .Value directly
